# How to redirect to action from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an app that uses a large model.  It takes five view pages to collect all of the data.  I am keeping the model in session between view pages.  Sometimes the session dies after inactivity in the middle of the process.  When this happens, I want to push the user back to the Home page.

Here is part of my model:

```
        private MemberRegistration MemberRegistration {
        get {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["RegisterModel_MemberRegistration"] == null)
            {
               return null;
               >>>> I want to go back the home page here <<<<
            }
            return (MemberRegistration)HttpContext.Current.Session["RegisterModel_MemberRegistration"];
        }
        set {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["RegisterModel_MemberRegistration"] = value;
        }
    }
    public string FirstName {
       get {
           return MemberRegistration.FirstName;
       }
       set {
           MemberRegistration.FirstName = value;
       }
    }
```

My problem is this.  The model binding begins when the user clicks the "Next" button.  The model binding happens before the [HTTPPost] controller action.  If the session has expired, we hit the "return null" line.  I want to send the user back to the home page right then.

A secondary question - is there a better way to do this other than using the Session.  (Please don't suggest that we keep the partial registration in the database.  I'd rather have the problems with keeping it in the Session than the problems that arise from having a partial record in the database.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't. Have it return something meaningful to the controller.

Comment: Use an alternative to Session. Keep the partial registration in the database.

Comment: I don't get to the controller. The program errors when the binding gets to the get/set for FirstName when MemberRegistion.FirstName is not available because MemberRegistration is not available.  I need to stop the binding process from continuing ...

Comment: If I were starting from scratch, the database solution would be fine.  However, there are hundreds of existing programs that access these compound database tables. Inserting partial records would wreak absolute havoc!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Use jQuery UI and create Tabs. Use 5 tabs on single view page instead of 5 view pages - you won't have to break your model to pieces.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/